# How to I display an item that was created using collection_select when doing an Edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am modeling phone numbers and companies.

```
class AppPhoneNumberList < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :app_company_list_id

belongs_to :app_company_list
has_many :app_phone_no_perm_lists

 validates :phone_number, presence: true,
           uniqueness: true

 validates :phone_number, :length => 10..10

end
```

---||---

```
class AppCompanyList < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :app_exts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :app_company_maps, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :app_phone_number_lists, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :company_name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates :company_name, length: {maximum: 256}
end
```

When I create a phone number, I use collection_select in the phone_list form.html.erb to choose a company to own the new phone number.

This works fine.

```
<%= collection_select( :app_phone_number_list, :app_company_list_id, AppCompanyList.all, :id, :company_name ) %>
```

---||---

My question is, when I edit a phone number in the phone_number_list, how do I display the value I selected for the company_name when the phone_number_list item was created?

The default of collection_select seems to be the first item in the company_list. Can selecting the correct company_name be done in the phone_list form.html.erb or do I need a helper?

Comment: You should be able to use `{ selected: app_company_list.id }`. Please look for ":selected" in http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select.

Comment: Thanks. This worked.... <%= collection_select( :app_phone_number_list, :app_company_list_id, AppCompanyList.all, :id, :company_name, {:selected => @app_phone_number_list.app_company_list.id(&:id)} ) %>